# Elastic Search : Installing Sense

Tags: sense

I get error Installing Sense using kibana-plugin command

C:\Users\SJawahar\kibana-5.6.0-windows-x86\bin>kibana-plugin install file://C:/Users/SJawahar/sense-2.0.0-beta7.tar.gz
Attempting to transfer from file://C:/Users/SJawahar/sense-2.0.0-beta7.tar.gz
Install paths with file:// are deprecated, use file:/// instead
Transferring 1386775 bytes....................
Transfer complete
Retrieving metadata from plugin archive
Error: end of central directory record signature not found
    at C:\Users\SJawahar\kibana-5.6.0-windows-x86\node_modules\yauzl\index.js:17
9:14
    at C:\Users\SJawahar\kibana-5.6.0-windows-x86\node_modules\yauzl\index.js:53
9:5
    at C:\Users\SJawahar\kibana-5.6.0-windows-x86\node_modules\fd-slicer\index.j
s:32:7
    at FSReqWrap.wrapper [as oncomplete] (fs.js:682:17)
Plugin installation was unsuccessful due to error "Error retrieving metadata fro
m plugin archive"

Answer (score 0):

I am able to use sense from Kibana dev tools
http://localhost:5601